# how to parse and apply filter on xml file using logstash

Tags: xml, logstash

this is my xml file

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <animals>
      <animal>
         <name>cat</name>
         <age>5</age>
      </animal>
      <animal>
         <name>dog</name>
         <age>7</age>
      </animal>
   </animals>
   <information>
      <first>
         <garden>1</garden>
         <animal>cat</animal>
         <food>yes</food>
      </first>
      <first>
         <garden>2</garden>
         <animal>dog</animal>
         <food>yes</food>
      </first>
   </information>
</root>`
```

so what i wannt to do is to parse this xml exactly to extract every information about each animal for exemple cat : name age garden food is it possible ?

i tried to use this filter but it doesnt work

`

```
filter {
  xml {
    source => "message"
    store_xml => false
    xpath => [
      "//animal/name/text()", "name",
      "//animal/age/text()", "age",
      "//information/first[animal/text()=' %{name} ']/garden/text()", "garden",
      "//information/first[animal/text()=' %{name} ']/food/text()", "food"
    ]
  }
}
```

`